# ¿Deberíamos quemar la etiqueta [fetch]?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

Deseo proponer que eliminemos la etiqueta [fetch](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fetch) del sitio.

- Actualmente [hay 76 preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fetch) con esa etiqueta y creo que ninguna sería buscada con ese término. Todas se relacionan con una funcionalidad de algún framework, algún stack o algún lenguaje.
- No tiene wiki y creo que es difícil poner una, pues es una acción que puede darse / hacerse en diferentes capas de una aplicación. Sin contexto, no tiene sentido.
- Las preguntas con esta etiqueta van desde ReactJS y JS hasta docker, pasando por PHP.

¿Valdría la pena quemar esa etiqueta?

Answer (score 6):

De las 76 preguntas:

- 53 tienen además la etiqueta [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).
- Con la etiqueta [reactjs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) y sin [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) hay otras 9, algunas con [php](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- Con la etiqueta [nodejs](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodejs) hay otras 2 (sin contar de nuevo las que además tienen [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)).
  -Del mismo modo otras 2 tienen la etiqueta [ajax](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax)

Eso suma 66 preguntas de 76 que seguramente hacen referencia a [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

Creo que la etiqueta es válida, se usa correctamente en más del 80% de los casos y veo más útil eliminar la etiqueta en las preguntas de docker, sql, ...etc que quemarla.

Comment: Buena corrección. _I stand corrected_, dirían en el otro SO. Podríamos entonces a) quitarla de los que no tengan que ver con esa API, y b) documentar la etiqueta con la descripción de la API. +1

Comment: Habría que editar la orientación de la etiqueta para indicar que debe usarse en preguntas sobre la Fetch API y no para el comando fetch.

Comment: ¿Y renombrarla a [tag:fetch-js] para dejar claro que es de JavaScript y evitar que se reproduzca su uso incorrecto? (Soy bastante escéptico sobre la utilidad real del extracto de etiqueta indicando cuándo debe usarse)

Comment: @fedorqui totalmente de acuerdo

Comment: ¿Sabes si se hizo algo de todo esto? Creo que sigue igual

Answer (score 2):

Coincido con la [respuesta de Pablo Lozano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4534/83) en que mayoritariamente esta etiqueta está relacionada con JavaScript y, por tanto, está bastante bien definida.

Dado que *fetch* es un nombre bastante genérico y, independientemente del extracto que definamos, es muy probable que siga utilizándose erróneamente en algunos casos, **sugiero mantener la etiqueta pero renombrándola a [fetch-api](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fetch-api) para que sea más claro su uso**. De hecho [es así como está nombrada en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fetch-api), donde también tienen [*git-fetch*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-fetch).

Una vez hecho esto, lo suyo sería que la comunidad reetiquetara las preguntas que la usan erróneamente.